# Appending multiple file loads in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fairly new to python, been coding in it for about a year or so. My company is switching from using SAS and a Netezza database for some of our data management. In order to access certain information, I have to load .dat.gz files now using Python3 in unix. In order to access similar information I used to access using basic SQL queries, I now have to import a list of files containing similar information and sort it using python. While this is not an issue for most of the data, there is an instance where I am running into performance issues. In order to access certain data I need, I must load over 300 files to python and try to append them together. This is an issue as the program takes a long time just to load the data. I am currently using pandas `read_csv` using `usecols` option to limit the data to the three columns I need. I first used `df.append(df2)`, but it was slow. I then changed the dataframe to list, but that still did not seem to improve performance that much. All together the data contains over 50 Million rows. While I do not expect this program to run in seconds, I would like some help to improve performance where I can.

Just to note it is important to keep the integrity of the original .dat.gz files. The files I read in very in size from 2 rows to 50k rows or more. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried `df.append(df2)` and concatenating lists. I also tried appending the data to a new CSV in my working directory so the data would not all be stored while the program was running. That did not improve performance either.

```py
import pandas as pd
import sys

#function to read in directories list from agrv[1]
def import_file_list(file_name):
    file_list = []
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for row in f:
            row = row.strip()
            file_list.append(row)
    return file_list

#main loop to read in all files and append the data
def import_data(list_of_files)
    for count, item in enumerate(list_of_files):
        exposure_data = pd.read_csv(item, sep='|', usecols=['A', 'B', 'C'], compression='gzip')
            if count == 0:
                    data_dict = exposure_data.to_dict('split')
                    values_list = list(data_dict['data'])
            else:
                    temp_dict = exposure_data.to_dict('split')
                    temp_list = list(temp_dict['data'])
                    values_list = values_list + temp_list

def main():
    import_data(import_file_list(sys.argv[1]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Expected results would be to loop through all the files I need and combine them to one dataframe, list of lists, dictionary of all the data, or whatever object is most efficient with the three columns I need to do my calculations.

Comment: What is MM? Mega millions (10^12)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A suggestion that may help is to make generators of loops in `import_file_list` and `import_data`. 
This is more memory efficient on the intermediate steps and defers building the dataframe until the end.

```py
def import_file_list(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for row in f:
            yield row.strip()


def import_data_to_dfs_iter(list_of_files)
    for item in list_of_files:
        yield pd.read_csv(
            item, sep='|', usecols=['A', 'B', 'C'], compression='gzip')

def main():
    dfs_iter = import_data_to_dfs(import_file_list(sys.argv[1]))
    df = pd.concat(dfs_iter)
```

Comment: I am testing this out now. Is there a place where I can add a print statement to show the number of files being loaded from the import. I am assume I can add a print statement after the df = pd.concat(dfs_iter) for the total count. I just want to make sure things align.

Comment: I added a print statement at the end appears to have worked. The processing time went way down thank you.

Comment: Great news! Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the functional improvements that were already presented to you, there are also a few non-functional facets that could be improved.

Python has an official [Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), often just called PEP8. This guide presents a variety of recommendations to write consistent and good looking Python code.

IMGO the points most relevant to your code would be:

1. Sort the [imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports). Standard library imports come first, followed by third-party libraries, and eventually local import from other Python files you have written.
2. Write proper [documentation strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings). The officially recommended docstring syntax is to enclose them in `"""triple quotes"""` and place them immediately below the function definition. Apart from a unified style with most of the Python coding world, this will also make sure that Python's built-in `help(...)` function as well as most proper Python IDEs will easily pick it up and show it to you.
3. Use 4 spaces per [indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) level. There is an overindented block in the body of the `if` statement in `import_data`.

There are a lot of tools that may help you to keep a consistent style even on a larger scale. Some of these tools would be [pylint](https://pylint.org/) (style and static code checking), [flake8](http://flake8.pycqa.org/), [black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (style check and auto-formatting), or [yapf](https://github.com/google/yapf) (style check and auto-formatting) to name a few. Most Python IDEs support at least some of these tools so they will mark violating pieces of code while you write them and not just afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have heard of PEP8, but I have not looked into at this point. I been mainly working on the functionality and efficiency in my code. Plus, all the functionality that python offers. Can be overwhelming at times, but I do enjoy it.